# How to lose selection focus of a QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, selection, qwidget, qtextedit

I have a readonly **QTextEdit**. I'm able to select the text and copy it.
**What I need to do**: When the user is in selection mode(selecting text), if he **leaves the area** (with the left mouse button still holding) the widget must **lose focus and selection focus must end too**. When **mouse exits** out of bounds I want to be **similar to mouse release**. I tried to set this:

```
rootWidget->clearFocus();
rootWidget->close();
rootWidget->releaseMouse();
```

but even though visually the widget seems out of focus I still receive the `TextEdit::mouseMoveEvent()` of my widget.

I also tried to set focus to a dummy widget. The dummy widget gets focused but my textedit sitll gets mouseMoveEvent().

**How can I lose focus of the widget completely without releasing the mouse button?**

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: QWidget has method `grabMouse()`. Try call this with your dummy widget. And then call `releaseMouse()`

Answer (score 0):

You can give the focus to something else using `QWidget::setFocus()`. you should probably clear the selection before changing focus.

Comment: But how to clear the selection? This is my problem :)

Comment: oh sorry. 2 things you can try: [`QTextEdit::moveCursor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#moveCursor) or you create a new `QTextCursor` and use `QTextEdit::setTextCursor`. Do not use `QTextEdit::textCursor()` as it will only return a copy of it (you will need to call setTextCursor afterwards).